# Should I use jshint or eslint to lint a jquery plugin?

Tags: jquery, jshint, eslint

I can't grasp the Jshint instructions in the JQuery style guide at : 
https://contribute.jquery.org/style-guide/js/#linting

Jshint can't be found on JQuery core github. I can't see any .jshintrc file in the source. It's plenty of eslint stuff, though, but with no clear instruction.

What should I do in order to lint the JQuery way ?

Answer (score 0):

Documentation says:

> The following common options must be used in all projects:
>   
>   `{
>       "boss": true,
>       "curly": true,
>       "eqeqeq": true,
>       "eqnull": true,
>       "expr": true,
>       "immed": true,
>       "noarg": true,
>       "quotmark": "double",
>       "smarttabs": true,
>       "trailing": true,
>       "undef": true,
>       "unused": true
>   }`

so just create a .jshintrc file with that content in your project's root and run `jshint` (which you've already installed, right?) or use [grunt-jshint](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jshint) if you like complications.

Comment: Thanks. Some Jquery contributors added here that they rather use eslint now, and that the jquery.org doc maybe globally deprecated :
https://github.com/jquery/jquery.com/issues/155#issuecomment-268924532

Comment: moved to : [https://github.com/jquery/contribute.jquery.org/issues/14](https://github.com/jquery/contribute.jquery.org/issues/141) :
one should use a specific linter + linter config for each Jquery subproject, depending on what's provided in each subproject repo.